# Docker gremlin-server: "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm kind of green with Docker so forgive me if this is obvious.

I have two docker containers that I'm trying to get to talk. One is running an instance of [gremlin-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/tinkerpop/gremlin-server/) right out of the box. I started it with the command 
`docker run --name="gremlin-server" -p 8182:8182 tinkerpop/gremlin-server`

The other is running a lambda function using [lambci](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/). To run my basic test function I use the command `docker run --rm -v "$PWD"/lambda:/var/task -v "$PWD"/layer:/opt lambci/lambda:python3.6 test_containers.lambda_handler`

Here is my test_containers.py code:

```
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    gremlin_url = 'ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'
    g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection(gremlin_url, 'g'))
```

Here is the error I'm getting back from the lambda function:

```
{
   "errorMessage":"[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address",
   "errorType":"OSError",
   "stackTrace":[
      [
         "/var/task/test_containers.py",
         7,
         "lambda_handler",
         "g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection(gremlin_url, 'g'))"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py",
         45,
         "__init__",
         "password=password)"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/client.py",
         76,
         "__init__",
         "self._fill_pool()"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/client.py",
         92,
         "_fill_pool",
         "conn = self._get_connection()"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/client.py",
         105,
         "_get_connection",
         "self._transport_factory, self._executor, self._pool)"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py",
         40,
         "__init__",
         "self.connect()"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py",
         46,
         "connect",
         "self._transport.connect(self._url)"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/tornado/transport.py",
         33,
         "connect",
         "lambda: websocket.websocket_connect(url))"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py",
         458,
         "run_sync",
         "return future_cell[0].result()"
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py",
         238,
         "result",
         "raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)"
      ],
      [
         "<string>",
         4,
         "raise_exc_info",
         ""
      ],
      [
         "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py",
         1117,
         "connect",
         "self.socket.connect(address)"
      ]
   ]
}
```

So I'm not sure if 
a. I'm using the correct url to access the server, and 
b. I need to do some more setup to get them to talk.

I'm running docker on windows. I could set up a ubuntu VM to run them in but that seems... redundant. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of    gremlin_url = 'ws://localhost:8182/gremlin' try    gremlin_url = 'ws://host.docker.internal:8182/gremlin' or whatever your docker container host name is.